# GFCI trips every 10 min 7 sec

Tags: gfci

20 amp GFCI installed upstream from new 20 amp receptacle where only load is refrig. I plugged refrig into a new 15 amp GFCI across the hall and it doesn’t trip. Both GFCIs are on same breaker but are not linked together. I guess they are junctioned somewhere in the ceiling.

Comment: Why is the refrigerator on GFCI in the first place?  Is it in a garage or basement?  Because fridges tripping GFCIs is surprisingly common.  And they're not really the use-case for GFCI; it's not like someone is going to drop it in a sink full of water.

Comment: GFCI are striktly not recommended by some manufacturers for feeding fridge. Read the manual.

Comment: Every 10:07 is very specifically consistent. Sounds like every time the compressor kicks on in the fridge.

Comment: It is possible that is the self test cycle of that GFCI and it is more sensitive than the other one you had plugged into, like others have said a fridge on a GFCI is asking for spoiled food.

Comment: If it's one receptacle and nothing else on a new 20A breaker just for the fridge why did you install a GFCI outlet?  What do you mean by "they are junctioned"?

Comment: @jay613 , the op is basically stating that the GFCI is a branch not a daisy chain. There is a junction that they both are fed from. I know with some track home the basic wiring package only had required circuits but the upgraded package could have 3-4 additional breakers,  how is this done a j box in the attic or crawl space is like a spider with 1 circuit. Purchase the upgrade and additional feeders are run to that J box and broken out now the reefer, dining room, and kitchen are separated out and on their own circuits, similar with bedrooms and bathrooms where it was 1 bath circuit now 2-3.